# Yii web application ownership and permissions

Tags: linux, yii

I have a php application uploaded on my server. It is written in yii framework.
www-data is the owner and group of the project root folder.
permission is set currently to  775 recursively.

but app is not working. I get following error in the browser:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /task/site/login was not found on this server.
```

Any idea how can I correct the situation?

Comment: Did you set up [.htaccess](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/214/url-hide-index-php/) on server? Which server are you using?

Comment: Not yet. I am using Apache